# Why is ZipArchive setEncryptionName not working?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have PHP **v7.3** and I'm running the following PHP code, trying to create a password protected ZIP-file.

The ZIP-file is created, but it's not password protected. What could be wrong?

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipFile = $this->backupDir . '/' . $db_file_name . '_' . $this->backupFormat . '.sql.zip ';
    if (file_exists($zipFile)) { unlink($zipFile); }
    
    $zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $password = 'top-secret';
    $zip->setPassword($password);
    $fileName = $this->backupDir . '/' . $db_file_name . '.sql';
    $baseName = basename($fileName);
    $zip->addFile($fileName, $baseName);
    $zip->setEncryptionName($fileName, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256);
    $zip->close();
```

I'm not getting any errors. It's just that he generated ZIP-file is unprotected.

Comment: I am doing the same thing as you. For me the file is being protected, but the password is not accepted when trying to open the zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking out `phpinfo`, you see libzip version is used. This must be increased to version 1.2.0 or newer.

Comment: I am using PH 7.3 and Libzip 1.8, but still not working. In my case the password that is being used to encrypt is not working when unlocking the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same. I have tried it in many different ways but it didn't work for me under Linux using PHP 8.0. I have tried it on 2 different linux servers.
Libzip is installed and the recommended (1.2.x) version is used.

At the end I used the other way that is recommended by many other developers:

```
<?php
$password    = 'get the password by some secure way';
$zipFileName = sprintf('compressed_file--%s-%s.zip', (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d'), mt_rand(0, 99999));
$zipFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . $zipFileName;
$contentFilePath = 'some_file_prepared_in_tmp_folder.xls';

system('cd /tmp; zip -P ' . $password . ' ' . $zipFilePath . ' ' . $contentFilePath);
?>
```